# XeLaTeX + biber cannot handle umlauts and ć in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, xetex, biber, accents

This is a minimum working example of my original document.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}
@article{luka,
  author = {Luka Modri\'{c}},
  journal = {Euro},
  pages = {1--2},
  title = {Birkh\"{a}user},
  year = 2016
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
% for biblatex with biber
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=alphabetic,
  citestyle=alphabetic,
  backref=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}

\begin{document}
Test Modri\'{c} in Birkh\"auser \cite{luka}.

%%% bibliography
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

As you can see, the special characters `\"{a}` and `\'{c}` works well in the main document but they don't in the bibliography.

[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: Add `\usepackage{fontspec}`

Comment: Either use utf8 characters, or let the package xunicode help you with translating tex sequences to utf8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't make much sense to use XeLaTeX without `fontspec`. In particular, you can see that the `.bbl` file contains

```
\refsection{0}
  \sortlist[entry]{anyt/global/}
    \entry{luka}{article}{}
      \name{author}{1}{}{%
        {{hash=8778d2a5968de5f48517c0ace345d5a1}{%
           family={Modrić},
           family_i={M\bibinitperiod},
           given={Luka},
           given_i={L\bibinitperiod}}}%
      }
```

because Biber, given that the engine used is XeTeX, outputs UTF-8 characters. Indeed, you'd get the same missing glyphs if you input

```
Test Modrić in Birkhäuser \cite{luka}.
```

Full example

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{luka,
  author = {Luka Modri\'{c}},
  journal = {Euro},
  pages = {1--2},
  title = {Birkh\"{a}user},
  year = 2016
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
% for biblatex with biber
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=alphabetic,
  citestyle=alphabetic,
  backref=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Test Modrić in Birkhäuser \cite{luka}.

%%% bibliography
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]